# Cherokee force gzip compression for HTTP/1.0

Tags: http, gzip, compression, amazon-cloudfront, cherokee

I am using CloudFront with a Cherokee origin server for static files. Cherokee serves gzipped content for direct browser requests without any problem. But when CloudFront requests content, Cherokee serves it uncompressed because CloudFront is requesting it with HTTP/1.0 (but has header Accept-Encoding: gzip). Is there a way I can force gzip compression for HTTP/1.0 requests in Cherokee? My CloudFront costs are almost double because of this issue.

A similar issue exists for ngnix but fixable with a configuration change: http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/gzip-nginx-cloudfront/

Comment: So that's why Amazon doesn't implement HTTP/1.1.

Comment: CloudFront does have Accept-Encoding: gzip and accepts gzipped content fine.

Comment: Yes, but they can take you for lots of money until you notice the problem.

Comment: I somehow believe this. As a technical person it gives me no reason to do a HTTP/1.0 in this age.

Comment: Exactly. HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616) is almost 15 years old; not implementing it at least conditionally is ridiculous.